Android 11 package visibility - How do I query my own apps?
I have 3 apps. Application A needs app B and C to be installed to support full functionality. How do I check from app A if app B and C are installed?
I can't do
context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)

they don't show in
context.packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)

I have tried and added queries to app A
<queries>
    <package android:name="us.app.B" />
    <package android:name="us.app.C" />
</queries>

that doesn't work.
I can do:
val launchIntent =
    context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.apply {
        setAction(action)
    }
        ?:
        Intent(action).apply {
            setClassName(packageName, activity)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
if (extras != null)
    launchIntent.putExtras(extras)
try {
    context.startActivity(launchIntent)
    return true // installed
} catch (e: Exception) {
    return false // not installed
}

But I don't want to launch the app, I simply want to know if it is available.
I can change the code of all 3 apps, so there has to be some solution that I am missing...

"that doesn't work" -- what specifically do you mean by this? If you mean that getPackageInfo() does not work, it should, assuming that you have <queries> in the correct place in the manifest.

@CommonsWare That is exactly what I mean. getPackageInfo() returns NameNotFoundException. I have triple checked and my package name is correct. <queries> block is a direct child on <manifest>.

"I have tried and added queries to app A" -- the (fake) package names that you have here are for A and B. If this <queries> is in app A, you need the package names to be for B and C, not for A and B. My guess is that this is more of a typo in the redaction you did for the question, but I mention it just in case.

@CommonsWare my bad, you are right. That is in fact just a typo (I corrected it). Are you saying if things are as I say they are it should work?

Yes. I ran a bunch of tests when this came out, including getInstalledPackages(), and they worked fine. I did not test getPackageInfo() specifically.

After placing
<queries>
    <package android:name="us.app.B" />
    <package android:name="us.app.C" />
</queries>

in your AndroidManifest.xml, you can use
context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)

and it should work perfectly.
I created this function and it works well on my own device and apps
fun isAppInstalled(packageName: String, context: Context): Boolean {
    return try {
        context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }
}

and just call it
val isAppBInstalled = isAppInstalled("us.app.B", context)


That unfortunately doesn't work. I think there is something wrong with my device - I tried on a different tablet and it worked. The same device also has problems with rxJava that I can't reproduce anywhere else.

Good to know that it worked on the tablet! Like you said, it's about the device and not the procedure. Google wouldn't create different procedures for different devices. What's the device specifications anyways?
